# Navigating in the same scene with different props

Tags: react-native, react-redux, react-native-router-flux

I'm learning react-native with redux and I'm trying to make a kind of social network application.
My problem is: when I'm on a user-1 profile screen and I navigate to user-2 profile, so basically I navigate from Profile.js to Profile.js (same screen) with different props. The problem is when I press the 'back' button, I get the user-2 profile while I should see user-1 profile.
The profile informations are saved in the store with redux.
For navigation I use `Actions.sceneKey()` from react-native-router-flux.
I already tried :

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('profile', { key: someRandomKey });
```

I get "Promise returned from navigate is ignored".
T also tried to save every user profile informations that I visit in an array but I don't know how to manipulate this array when I press back button...

Comment: Check out Actions.pop();  https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-router-flux